# Cannot start into recovery

Tags: sony-xperia-z2

I did have dual recovery but after bricking the phone had to flash new FTF file. Ever since, I am unable to reboot into recovery. I've tried turning on the phone and pressing the volume up and volume down buttons but it just starts normally. I tried `adb reboot recovery` same thing. I have root on the phone. I also tried flashing a new recovery through adb but it fails with an error message.

Comment: Doesn't flashing FTF overwrite that recovery you've flashed?

Comment: @AndyYan that's a good question, I thought not but was just assuming

Comment: It certainly does from my experience (unless you excluded boot or FOTA partition when flashing, which is unlikely). Just flash one again.